# Weird Java behavior

Tags: java

I faced a weird java behavior on runtime. All information is on screenshot.
My application fails on it. Surprisingly, with the same input data at different times, it can be processed correctly. Can you explain me what is the cause of this weird behavior? I use jdk 1.7.0_79
Here full code part `id = "common.dto.IdsFilter"`

```
    private String[] splitPackageAndNameParts(String id) {
    // check string not empty
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected id : " + id);
    }

    // get last point index
    int index = id.lastIndexOf(".");

    // check index
    if (index == 0 || index >= (id.length() - 1)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected id : " + id);
    }

    // split
    String pkgPart = index < 0 ? "" : id.substring(0, index + 1);
    String namePart = id.substring(index + 1, id.length());

    // return result
    return new String[]{pkgPart, namePart};
}
```

The right result should be `pkgPart = "common.dto."`, but on runtime it returns `"common.dto"` (without dot)

[image]

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: We need *actual code* here.  We can't help you out with a screenshot since *we* can't plug that in to our copies of IntelliJ to see what's going on.

Comment: Please edit your answer to clarify: what input data you use, what is the expected behavior and what error message do you get. And post the code that you have (no screenshot, but real java code) so we can help you.

Comment: Added code part @Makoto

Comment: @jahra: why you need to `+1` to get `pkgPart`?

Comment: What's `id` defined as?  Your example should be as complete as possible.

Comment: @Makoto: i'm sure that `id` is string used to get dot index.

Comment: Add full method. @Makoto

Comment: You forgot to say what the actual error/exception is.

Comment: You are right @ManhLe

Comment: @jahra: do you mean the correct answer is `pkgPart = common.dto` and `namePart = IdsFilter`?

Comment: The right result should be pkgPart = "common.dto.", but on runtime it returns "common.dto" (without dot) @ManhLe

Comment: If it is that you are trying to omit the `.` on the end, just don't include it in the `substring` range - `String pkgPart = index < 0 ? "" : id.substring(0, index);`

Comment: It works correctly on other input data, tthe problem is that it returns an incorrect value only for this case and only at concrete step of application running @AndyTurner

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, it looks like an off-by-one error in your substring.  What you want to do is encapsulate up to but *not including* the location of the period's index spot, since that would also include the period in the substring.

Simple change:  remove the `+ 1` from the substring operation.

Alternatively, with Java 8, there's a clearer way to do this using `StringJoiner` and `String#split`.  This will get you the first element; the second element is simply the last one in the split collection.

```
String[] split = pkg.split("\\.");
final StringJoiner stringJoiner = new StringJoiner(".");
for(int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
    stringJoiner.add(split[i]);
}
System.out.println(stringJoiner.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have the same problem. I removed `+1` from substring operations, it works fine in tests, without any problem. But now `.` missed in `namePart` on runtime. When I evaluate it returns correct result, but on runtime it fails ( the same problem as on screenshot)

Comment: I noticed, that the first call of method with `"common.dto.IdsFilter"` as input works fine and returns the correct value. But if I call this method immediately after first call with the same `"common.dto.IdsFilter"` as input it will return wrong result